# JS SVG getCTM and setCTM?

Tags: javascript, svg

If I use getCTM() to get the current tranformation matrix, how do I use that object to set the matrix if I want to restore it at a later point (I know about save and restore but those refer to the canvas and not items)

I know I set the attribute:

```
var m = someitem.getCTM();
$(someitem).attr("transform", "matrix("+m.a+","+m.b+","+m.c+","+ m.d+","+m.e+","+m.f+")");
```

But that seems sort of a long way of doing it. I can't find a setCTM function of any such close function.

Developing for webkit if that makes a difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var transform = ownerSVGElement.createSVGTransform()

transform.setMatrix(elem.getCTM())

someelement.transform.baseVal.initialize(transform)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
function setCTM(someitem,m) {
  return someitem.transform.baseVal.initialize(
    someitem.ownerSVGElement.createSVGTransformFromMatrix(m));
}
```

If, instead of saving `someItem.getCTM()`, you save `someitem.transform.baseVal.getitem(0)`, you can use:

```
function setTransform(someitem,t) {
  return someitem.transform.baseVal.initialize(t));
}
```