# Connect 2 svg elements

Tags: javascript, svg

There has been a lot of questions regarding the coördinate system of svg elements but no one has got me solving my problem.

Look at this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/archemedia/4f54jnm8/

In the startup function, I added `connect("A", "B")` which connects element A and B with the line.
When I try to `connect("A", "D")` the line doesn't position correctly, due to the transform attribute of element D.

Could someone provide me with a clear solution?
I don't want to use a svg library, I just want plain javascript code which solves the problem, preferably by adding it to the fiddle.

Many thanks

Comment: `getCTM` will enable you to get the (cumulative) transform matrix, which you can apply to the coordinates. You may have to apply the SVG’s inverse matrix as well.

Comment: What's the SVG's inverse matrix?

Comment: `theSVGelement.getCTM().inverse()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getMid` function needs to account for the transform matrix of the rectangles.

```
function getMid (rect, svg) {
  let point = svg.createSVGPoint();
  point.x = rect.x.baseVal.value + rect.width.baseVal.value / 2;
  point.y = rect.y.baseVal.value + rect.height.baseVal.value / 2;
  return point.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(rect.getScreenCTM()));
}
```

Note the new `svg` parameter. This is your `SVGSVGElement`. In the fiddle, you can grab it with `document.getElementById('Laag_1')`.

<sub>Normally, I'd cite the relevant pages on MDN, but their SVG documentation is lacking. I had to piece this together from [a couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281732/js-svg-getctm-and-setctm) of [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33579187/how-can-i-apply-an-svgmatrix-to-an-array-of-points). The key was searching "svg get transform matrix" and following the rabbit hole from there.</sub>

Comment: Indeed, when changing the percentual size of the svg, the line is at a different place. Any idea how to solve that?

Comment: By brute-forcing every combination of `svg`, `rect`, `getCTM()`, `getScreenCTM()`, `inverse()`, and `multiply()`, yes! My brain's not... at its best, right now.

Comment: I would recommend you avoid using `getScreenCTM`, as implementations are buggy and not consistent between browsers. Using `getCTM` should in this case be appropriate.

Comment: @jcaron Testing in Firefox, `svg.getCTM()` is null, and `return point.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(rect.getCTM()));` yields incorrect results. `return point.matrixTransform(rect.getCTM());`, my original answer, yields incorrect results depending on the CSS size of the SVG.

Comment: Replying from my phone so can’t really test, but you should need both matrices (the element’s and the SVG’s), and they should both come from the same function. Surprised getCTM returns null on the SVG element. A workaround may be to add a <g> inside the SVG and use that?

Answer (score 0):

This is by far the most correct and useful answer and it might server the community. I've searched a lot and got multiple workarounds with regex and custom functions, all of which didn't work. My problem is finally solved.
I updated the fiddle with the answer from AuxTaco and the getCTM() tweak suggested by jcaron. Thanks everyone!

```
function getMid(rect, svg){
        var point = svg.createSVGPoint();
        point.x = rect.x.baseVal.value + rect.width.baseVal.value / 2;
        point.y = rect.y.baseVal.value + rect.height.baseVal.value / 2;
        return point.matrixTransform(svg.getCTM().inverse().multiply(rect.getCTM()));
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/archemedia/4f54jnm8/2/